# Find name of directories that don't contains specific subdirectories

Tags: shell, find

I have several directories like so :

```
Rep1/foo/bar/files

Rep2/foo/otter/files

Rep3/foo/bar/files
```

...

What i'd like to have is the name of the directories that doesn't have the subdirectory */bar/ and possibly remove them. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you really want *all* directories without a `bar` subdirectory or do you want only the *top level* directories, in this case `Rep2/`? Strictly speaking `Rep2/foo` and `Rep1/foo/otter` also contain no `bar`. Same goes for `C/` in `/A/bar/C/`.

Comment: I just want the name of the top level directories in order to remove them afterwards

Comment: How about the depth of the directory tree... will it be a static 3 subdirectories ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. First, what OS is this on? Can we assume GNU tools or not? Second, as others have said, please clarify your desired output, whether the directory structure is always the same, whether you can have things like `Rep2/foo/bar/files` as well as `Rep2/foo/otter/files`. And, if yes, should `Rep2/foo/otter/` be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following script using `find`

```
for topdir in ./*/; do
    [ -z "$(find "$topdir" -type d -name bar -print -quit)" ] &&
    echo "$topdir"
done
```

<sub>The `-print -quit` part is just an optimization to exit once a `bar/` sub-directory is found. If your version of `find` doesn't support `-quit` you can just remove that part. The command will still work but could be a tiny bit slower.</sub>

or this pure `bash` script

```
shopt -s globstar
for topdir in ./*/; do
    (cd "$topdir" && compgen -G '**/bar/' > /dev/null) ||
    echo "$topdir"
done
```

If you are happy with the results replace `echo "$topdir"` with `rm -r "$topdir"` to delete the directories.

Both approaches can handle arbitrary file/directory names, even such with linebreaks or special symbols like `*` in them.

Comment: Note that `-quit` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Luckily it's only an optimization. Non-GNU `find` users can still use the same approach. I edited the answer to point out how to do it.

Comment: Does the `-print` do anything useful here? Won't `find "$topdir" -type d -name bar -print -quit` d exactly the same thing as `find "$topdir" -type d -name bar -quit`?

Comment: The `-print` is needed because of the `-quit`. If `-quit` wasn't there then `-print` could be left out. You can test it yourself: `find / -print -quit` prints `/` but `find / -quit` prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash command line to find all `**/files` subdirectories whithout `/bar/` in the path:

```bsh
find . -type d -name files | grep --invert-match /bar/
```

It gets you an output:

```
./Rep2/foo/otter/files
```

Now if you want to list only top level directories use:

```
find . -type d -name files | grep --invert-match /bar/ | cut --delimiter / --fields 2
```

It gives you:

```
Rep2
```

Comment: With the assumption that there is always exactly one `files/` directory you could as well use `find -type d -name files -not -path '*/bar/*' | cut -d/ -f2` instead of the the `find`+`grep` combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 ! -iname bar -type d | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'

Rep2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
has_bar() () (($#)) ${1-$REPLY}/*/bar(N/)

echo rm -rf rep*(/^+has_bar)
```

Or in a single command:

```
echo rm -rf rep*(/^e'[() (($#)) $REPLY/*/bar(N/)]')
```

(remove `echo` when happy)